# Problem with calling C function in Python

Tags: python, c, types

I want to call a function written in C via Python. For this task I've created three files in directory:

```
csquare.c
csquare.so
script.py
```

The file called csquare.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
double math_square(double x) {
     return x*x;
 }
```

script.py:

```
import ctypes
import os

def Main():
    os.system('cc -fPIC -shared -o csquare.so csquare.c')
    so_path = str(os.getcwd()) + '/csquare.so'
    cfunctions = ctypes.CDLL(so_path)
    cfunctions.math_square.argtypes = [ctypes.c_double]

    print(cfunctions.math_square(90.0))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main()
```

The problem is that the program always prints "1". What am I doing wrong? If I change the type of `math_square` function to `"int"` everything works fine.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is missing in your python source:

```
cfunctions.math_square.restype = ctypes.c_double
```

The return type by default is `ctypes.c_int`:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#return-types